# unknown type name in header when class is included

Tags: objective-c, class, types, header, singleton

I've got the following header file - for a singleton to store a couple of global variables..

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "SamplePad.h"

@interface dataManager : NSObject
{
    SamplePad *samplePad;
}

+ (id)sharedDataManager;

- (void) receiveSamplePad : (SamplePad*) sPad;

@end
```

But for some reason the compiler is giving me this error - 'Unknown tyoe name: 'SamplePad'
even though i've included it's header.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of including the header file, you can just place a

```
@class SamplePad;
```

before the start of

```
@interface dataManager ...
```

You still have to include the header in your implementation file for dataManager.

Answer (score 0):

aahh!

It was because 'SamplePad.h' was importing this dataManager header too.. I had to remove the #import at the top of it.. Works fine now.